# How to get array from array?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code

```
while ($itog = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
     $week=$itog["week"];
     if( $week <= 7 ){
         if($todayweek == $week){
              $itog["today"] =  $todaydate ;
         }
     }

    if($week == 8){
          $startdate =$itog["startdate"] ;
          if ($startdate == $todaydate){
                $itog["today"] =  $todaydate ;
          }
     }

            if($week == 9){
          $startdate =$itog["startdate"] ;
            $enddate =$itog["enddate"] ;
            if( $startdate <= $todaydate && $todaydate <= $enddate){
$itog["today"] =  $todaydate ; 
          }
     }
    $massiv[] = $itog;
}
```

And this is result:

> {
>   id: "7",
>   imgsrc: "",
>   nazv: "Клвав",
>   week: "8",
>   startdate: "2015-01-25",
>   enddate: "0000-00-00"
>   }
>
> {
>   id: "8",
>   imgsrc: "",
>   nazv: "Пятый день",
>   week: "5",
>   startdate: "2015-01-04",
>   enddate: "2015-04-18"
>   }
>
> {
>   id: "9",
>   imgsrc: "",
>   nazv: "Тупой Текуще",
>   week: "9",
>   startdate: "2015-01-20",
>   enddate: "2015-02-01",
>   today: "2015-01-26"
>   }

As yo can see only last element of array have TODAY param... How can I make a new array  with only elements has TODAY?

Comment: Hello, can you explain the structure of the new array?

Comment: @OhhMee
Hello! I want to get only elements wich have TODAY
And structure like
ID,
IMGSRC
NAZV
WEEK
STARTDATE
ENDDATE
TODAY

Comment: using array_key_exists('today', $itog), it will return true or false. to check if $itog have 'today' index. then add $itog in your new array

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you can do something like this to get only elements which have a today parameter:

This should be used after you `while()` loop

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($massiv as $ma) {
    if (array_key_exist('today', $ma)) {
        $newArray[] = $ma;
    }
}
```